# Render to particular Page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below the page I need to redirect. But I couldn't find redirect to below page  in rails

```
http://localhost:3000/custom_group/addToUserGroups?contoller=custom_group
```

I am using below form tag for navigating above page.I am not finding link_to option as well.

```
 <%= form_tag(contoller: "custom_group", action: "addToUserGroups") do%>
     <%=submit_tag "Add to User Group",class: "btn mx-auto btn-primary",  style: "width: 200px"%> 
      <% end %>
```

Comment: No.I have tried redirect: back but it is not working

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You can pass a param to the action that could interact with your paginator. https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/pagination-in-rails-and-how-to-implement-go-to-page-functionality-3218cef6db43